# Add variable to an existing json object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

```
request = myService.getCases();
request.then(
function(payload) {
$scope.cases = payload.data;

var time =  Math.floor((Date.now() - Date.parse($scope.cases[i].date_case_modified))/(60000*60*24));

$scope.cases.duration.push(time);
}
});
```

Inside the controller I am trying to tack on the cases.duration onto the cases object but it wont add it onto the object that is returned. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the type of `duration`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to introduce a `forEach` as shown here:

```
request = myService.getCases();
request.then(
    function(payload) {
         $scope.cases = payload.data;

         angular.forEach($scope.cases, function (el) {
            var time =  Math.floor((Date.now() - Date.parse(el.date_case_modified))/(60000*60*24));

            el.duration = time;
        });
    }
});
```

Hope this helps